# Length of line projected onto a horizontal line at some angle.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry, angle

Please see the image to understand my question:

[image: 2d lines projected onto horizontal floor]

Given the angle `theta`, and 3 parallel lines, the top line being 5 unit distances away from the middle line. How do I calculate the length of the line segment labelled `?` in the image?

Comment: $\sin$ is your friend.

Comment: sine takes an angle in radians and returns a number between -1 and +1, how does that help me?

Comment: $\sin(\mathrm{theta})=5/\mathrm{?}$. Now solve for ?.

Comment: so `5/sin(theta)` thank you

Comment: You're welcome.